# A complex condition inside v-if

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a complex condition to pass to the `v-if` directive.

I have tried the following.

```
<div v-if="(order.order_products[key].statuses[0].id) != 3 || order.status != 3" >
```

Can I add a complex condition in Vue's `v-if`? This is not working.

I also tried with `&&` but that wasn't working, either. I haven't found anything in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your question.

> Can I add a complex condition in Vue's `v-if`?

You **can** pass an arbitrary JavaScript expression to the `v-if` directive in Vue, including a complex boolean expression which contains operators `||` or `&&`.

You can test this on your own. For example, try having the following template.

```
<div v-if="true && false">I am not visible!</div>
```

Of course, you might try out something less trivial, too:

```
<div v-if="1 == 2 || (1 + 2 == 3 && 4 == 4)">I am visible!</div>
```

---

Your expression looks good, but based on the provided information it's impossible to deduce what exactly is wrong.

Your problem is something else: maybe the data is not in the format you thought it would be, or maybe your logic has a flaw in it.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can set complex condition. I suggest you to use [Vue computed fields](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), so you will have better highlight (through Vue Devtools) of variables which use in v-if expression. I suppose that order is data field, so you can set computed fields like this:

```
computed: {
    orderStatusId: function () {
        // Write some checks is variable defined/undefined
        return this.order.order_products[key].statuses[0].id
    },
    orderStatus: function () {
        return this.order.status
    }
}
```

and v-if expression should look like this:

```
<div v-if="orderStatusId !== 3 || orderStatus !== 3" >
```

In this approach you can review values of variables in your v-if expression.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use any JavaScript expresion inside v-if quotes.
But I recommend you to create a function or computed function and to call it inside your if statement, for better readability.

ex:

```
computed: {
  shouldDisplay: function () {
    return this.order.order_products[key].statuses[0].id) !== 3 || this.order.status !== 3;
  }
  ...
}

<div v-if="shouldDisplay"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
v-if="(segmento != 4) && (segmento != 2) && (segmento != 8)"
```

Works like a breeze for me!